# How to change the location of an addon in the UI

Tags: python, add-on

Some addons allow the user to select or name the tab in the *N* panel, most do not. Too many addons want their own tab.

How can I edit the ini script to change the location of the tool/addon?

I would like to move some addons into existing tabs and/or create new tabs to group the addons to my liking.

I know very little about Python scripting. I have Text Wrangler on my Mac and Notepad ++ on my PC. I've looked at many of the scripts and seen an entry for "Location" but I'm not sure exactly how to format the changes.

Where exactly can I find the necessary Python information. I'll do the required homework, I just need to know what to look for and where to look for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*It's not a good idea to do that, but here is how anyway. Be aware that this may break add-ons.*

What you need to be looking for is were the panels because they determine were UI elements are placed. The panel classes can be identified by their inheritance from `bpy.types.Panel`, although depending on how modules are imported it might just say `Panel`. Starting from Blender 2.8 there is a mandatory naming convention by which the class name of the panel should also contain `_PT_`.  Take as an example the following excerpt that defines a panel:

```
class SOME_COOL_ADDON_PT_settings(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "SOME_COOL_ADDON_PT_settings"
    bl_label = "Setting for cool addon"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "View" 

    ...
```

The placement in the UI is determined by `bl_space_type`, `bl_region_type` and `bl_category`. This means the panel is created in the 3D View in the right hand panel (which can open/close by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>) in the *View* tab. You could change the tab to *Tool* by changing the `bl_category = "Tool"`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and assistance. The first thing I'll do is disable most of my user addons, then spend more time refining my skills with Blender 2.80. Then I'll try each addon, one at a time to see if it's something I really need. Once I figure out which addons to keep and which ones to remove, then I make a decision to see if I need to mess with things.